# flutter batch http requests

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart

I am trying to send multiple http request to the google maps api to get the time taken for a journey. With the code below:

```
 getRouteCoordinates(LatLng sourceCords, LatLng destCords)async{
  String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=${sourceCords.latitude},${sourceCords.longitude}&destination=${destCords.latitude},${destCords.longitude}&key=$apiKey";
  http.Response response = await http.get(url);
  Map values = jsonDecode(response.body);
 
}
```

So I decide to use this package
[ [batching_future](https://pub.dev/packages/batching_future) ] , but I cant seem to understand how I can use this package to make it work.

I want to do this batch request with destination inputs like

```
  var inputs = [
    LatLng(43.721160, 45.394435),
    LatLng(23.732322, 78.385142),
    LatLng(21.721160, 90.394435),
    LatLng(13.732322, 59.385142),
    LatLng(47.721160, 80.394435),
    LatLng(25.732322, 60.385142),
  ];
```

How can I achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is `inputs` mapped to each `getRouteCoordinates` call?

Answer (score 0):

The [gmaps_multidestination](https://pub.dev/packages/gmaps_multidestination) package does the track.

The relevant code to run a batch request for travel times is copy and pasted below:

```dart
import 'package:google_maps_webservice/distance.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

/// Computes travel times from [myLocation] to [destinations] in batch using
/// Google Distance Matrix API and [apiKey].
///
/// Requires Google Maps API Key, Google Distance Matrix API, and is subject
/// to the limitations of the Matrix API (such as maximum destinations per
/// request)
Future<Map<Location, Duration>> batchTravelTimes(
        {@required Location myLocation,
        @required List<Location> destinations,
        @required String apiKey}) async =>
    (await GoogleDistanceMatrix(apiKey: apiKey)
            .distanceWithLocation([myLocation], destinations))
        .results
        .expand((row) => row.elements)
        .toList()
        .asMap()
        .map((i, location) => MapEntry(
            destinations[i], Duration(seconds: location.duration.value)));
```

The code to connect the above [batching_future](https://pub.dev/packages/batching_future) is:

```dart
/// Computes travel times from `O` to `[D1,D2,D3]` in batch.
/// Requires Google Maps API Key, Google Distance Matrix API, and is subject
/// to the limitations of the Matrix API (such as maximum destinations per
/// request)
import 'package:batching_future/batching_future.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_webservice/distance.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

typedef MyLocationProvider = Future<Location> Function();

BatchingFutureProvider<Location, Duration> batchingFutureTravelTime(
        {@required MyLocationProvider myLocationProvider,
        @required String apiKey}) =>
    createBatcher(
      (destinations) async => (await batchTravelTimes(
              apiKey: apiKey,
              myLocation: await myLocationProvider(),
              destinations: destinations))
          .values
          .toList(),
      maxBatchSize: 20,
      maxWaitDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
    );
```